# Do I need a different socket on client side for listening and sending?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am new to socket programming. The scenario is that:

1- I am creating a UDP socket, `fd`

2- Binding `fd` to an IP address/port

3- `recvfrom`()ing on the socket `fd` from destination, D

Now if I want to `sendto()` some data back to D, can I use the same socket, by passing in the `sockaddr_in` containing the IP address and port of D? Or do I need to create a new socket and do `bind()`?

Edit: From the first answer, it seems I do not need another socket, and do not need to bind() on that socket before transmitting. Is that correct?

Comment: *Receiving* and sending. Listening is a TCP concept, and happens at the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same UDP socket for both receiving and sending. To send directly to the peer you just received from, use the `sockaddr_in` structure that was filled in by `recvfrom`.

Comment: When I try sending over the same socket, sendto() returns -1

Comment: @Iceman If a socket function returns `-1` that means something went wrong, and you should check [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) for the error. Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to get a printable string of the error.

Comment: I am confused as to whether bind() needs to be called on the socket before using it for tx/rx

Comment: @Iceman Yes you need to bind it to a local address and port first, if you want to receive on that address/port.

Comment: I am using TI's NDK. I don't think their implementation sets errno. Anyway, strerror(errno) is "No Error"

Comment: @Iceman Better post your code, there's many ways you could have done that part wrong.

Comment: No, you don't need to bind, unless you need to use a specific port number.